# Store change is not detected by other component in React - MobX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx

I'm new to programming and I've been trying to learn React with MobX and I come across this problem where I updated my store using axios in homepage and when I check my store content in other page (adminPage.js) it is empty.

This is my Store component:

```
import { observable, action, decorate } from 'mobx'
import Axios from 'axios';
import { API_URL_1 } from '../components/url';

export var Product={
    list:[],
    cart:[],
    getList(){
        console.log('getList berjalan');
        Axios.get(API_URL_1 + '/products')
        .then(ok => {
            console.log(ok.data)
            Product.list = ok.data
        }).catch(error=>{
            console.log(error)
        })
        console.log(Product.list)
    },
    addToCartFunc(id){
        Product.cart.push(Product.list[id])
    },
    checkListContentFunc(){
        Product.list.map(data=>{
            console.log(data.id)
        })
    }
}

decorate(Product, {
    list : observable,
    cart : observable,
    getList : action,
    addToCartFunc : action
})
```

and this is the component that will render my store content:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Product} from '../store/Product'
import { observer, componentWillReact } from 'mobx-react';
import {withRouter} from 'react-router';

class AdminPage extends Component {
    renderProductList(){
        console.log('render list berjalan')
        console.log(Product.list)
        return(
            Product.list.map(Product=>{
                console.log(Product)
                return(
                    <tbody>
                        <td>{Product.id}</td>
                        <td>{Product.name}</td>
                        <td>{Product.price}</td>
                    </tbody>
                )
            })
        )
    }

    componentWillReact(){
        console.log("I will re-render, since the todo has changed!")
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <td>id</td>
                                <td>Name</td>
                                <td>Price</td>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        {this.renderProductList()}
                        <tbody>
                            <td><textarea ref="id"></textarea></td>
                            <td><textarea ref="name"></textarea></td>
                            <td><textarea ref="price"></textarea></td>
                            <td><input  type="button" value="Add"  className="btn btn-primary"/></td>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <input type="button" onClick={()=>{Product.checkListContentFunc()}} value="test"/>

                </div>
        )
    }
}

export default withRouter(observer(AdminPage))
```

Here's the link to my github's rep:
https://github.com/YoSoyAisoy/E-Commerce-React-MobX-

Sorry if this is a silly question.
Edit : added my codes

Comment: github repos frequently change. you should add the relevant code here.

Comment: hi, thank you for responding. I have added my codes in the post.